# Can I create a custom System Workflow Message for a particular Contribution Page?

Tags: receipts, smarty, custom-templates, system-workflow-messages

I need to create a custom system workflow message for

```
Contributions - Receipt (on-line)
```

that will be used instead of the default template when a particular contribution page is used.

I already know about the `Receipt` tab of the contribution page wizard. There I can prepend text to the receipt that is unique to that contribution page.

But I need to fuss with the template itself. I  know about the System Workflow Messages at: `civicrm/admin/messageTemplates`. The problem there is that the change applies to all contribution receipts. I'm looking to change the template only for a particular contribution page.

I'm using CiviCRM 4.5.8 on Drupal 7.36.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I learned [from @Nicholai in a previous (unrelated) thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/321/adding-a-facebook-conversion-pixel-code-to-the-contribution-confirmation-screen), you can override these templates with some pretty easy logic to add something custom to a single page. For example:

> {if $contributionPageID == 20}
>
> ```
> {* whatever you need to do on this page *}
> ```
>
> {/if}

I assume this would work in this case, too. If you try it and it works, let us know!

Comment: don't you need an {else} eg {if $contributionPageID == 20} DO THIS {else} DO THAT {/if} - i guess you don't if what you are saying for PageID==20 is in addition ;-)

Comment: Sounds about right!

Comment: Can I use this for the message template subject line, so I could have unique subject lines for each contribution form I have? Like this: {if $contributionPageID == 20} {ts 1=$title}Event Registration Receipt: %1{/ts}
{elseif $contributionPageID == 21} {ts 1=$title}Membership Receipt: %1{/ts}
{elseif $contributionPageID == 2} {ts 1=$title}Receipt for item purchase: %1{/ts}
{else} {ts 1=$title}Generic: %1{/ts}
{/if}

Comment: @A.Block yes.  However, you're likely better off using CiviRules to manage your receipts instead.

Comment: civiRules sounds interesting. I've installed the extension, and I can see how to set a rule for when a specific contribution form is used, but how do I use it to change the subject line of the receipt message template?

Comment: Wondering if anyone has an example of how to use civiRules to customize the subject line of the receipt (on/offline) system message?