# I want to do something like "if campaign=xxx" {include footer} in System Workflow Messages

Tags: civievent, system-workflow-messages

My colleague wants to include an email footer/signature for the email confirmation sent for event registrations, but only for the events managed by their office.

I know it's something similar to the answer on this question : [Can I create a custom System Workflow Message for a particular Contribution Page?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/715/can-i-create-a-custom-system-workflow-message-for-a-particular-contribution-page)

But I'm just looking for the text required for campaigns. I've got as far as working out that the campaign ID=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to find out if the campaign id is assigned to a variable available in the message template.

I can't test right now, but if you enable debugging and add a {debug} if you template you *should* get a long and fugly table with all the variables available from the message.

then it's the same process as for the contribution page:

```
{if $campaignID == 1}
{* whatever you need to do on this message *}
{/if}
```

campaignID to be replaced by the variable available to the template as identified in the debug message.