# How can I add a banner image in the confirmation email for a particular event?

Tags: civievent, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

I have already customised the system generated email template with organisation banner & logo, but I am not able to figure out how to add a banner for a specific event which would be different than the generic banner? is it possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it in addition to the default/generic banner you can probably add it in at the top of the "Thank you and receipting" section of the event.

If you want to use it in place of the generic banner, you may need to customize the template with some If/Then logic, checking the event ID in the smarty template somehow. [Here's an example for a Contribution page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/734/26), perhaps you can do something similar in the Event page. (To find the variables you have to work with, try [inserting {debug} into the template](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/820/26) and then registering for the event to receive the email with the Smarty variables listed)

EDIT: Default message template can be changed like this

```
{if $event.id == '36'}
<p><img alt="" src="https://your.image.url.in.full" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;" /></p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Thank you. Receipting section is only Plain Text, so an image cannot be inserted. However the if/then logic with message template worked fine.

Comment: @tapash great!  Would you be willing to edit the final bit of code you needed into the bottom of the answer above for anyone coming in the future?