# How to insert a CiviCRM query link into Drupal main menu with Clean URLs enabled?

Tags: drupal, menu, global-menu

How do you add a CiviCRM query link such as:

```
index.php?q=civicrm/member/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1
```

Into a Drupal main menu with Clean URLs enabled?

With Clean URLs enabled, Drupal will strip out the `?q=`, breaking the link.

Desired outcome:
Drupal main menu.
Menu item "Members".
URL to "`civicrm/member/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [further info here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/87/how-do-i-change-the-default-urls-to-contribution-or-event-registration-pages), but I'd recommend setting up a Redirect (using [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect)) and using that URL in the menu. For example, the redirect URL could be **member/search** and then it redirects to **civicrm/member/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1**.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use "/civicrm/member/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1" in the link? That should work too.

Comment: I find that when I enter that into the path I receive the following error - "The path '/civicrm/member/search&force=1&qfKey=0&reset=1' is either invalid or you do not have access to it". While Laryn's solution works as desired. Thanks Parvez.