# Show the CiviCRM simple donate form on Drupal static page or node.

Tags: drupal, extension, simple-donate-form

I am using Simple Donate version
 1.2
I am trying to integrate 'simple donate' extension for drupal page and/or block.

I have tried it by initializing civicrm in custom block. CiviCRM is getting initialized properly.

I have jut tried to load /partials/simpledonate.html file using code in following file: 
com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate-1.2/js/simpledonate.js

```
$routeProvider.when('/donation', {
        templateUrl: resourceUrl + '/partials/simpledonate.html',
        controller: 'SimpleDonationCtrl'
      });
```

if the URL is '/donation' then it will load /partials/simpledonate.html
But it is not working.

Can anyone put the idea i.e. how to load CiviCRM extension in drupal block or page?

Any idea is appreciable..

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17570

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/87/how-do-i-change-the-default-urls-to-contribution-or-event-registration-pages/ might be of interest too, but most answers there are redirect solutions I think

Answer (score 1):

You can make a use of [Webform CiviCRM Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module which integrates civicrm donation pages with webform and webform can be used as block anywhere in the node, for that you would need [Webform blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_block) module.

Comment: Webform comes with in-built ability to show forms as blocks. I think this module adds additional functionality but isn't 'required'